# Manually optimizing efcore generated SQL

Tags: c#, mysql, ef-core-3.1

I'm using .netcore 3.1 with efcore 3.1 on a mysql database with a pomelo mysql connector

I have the following code

```
db.A.Where(a => itemsToQuery.Contains(a.Id))
  .Include(a => a.BMappings)
  .Include(a => a.CMappings)
```

This generates the equivalent SQL code of

```
select * from a
  join b_mapping b on b.a_id = a.id
  join c_mapping c on c.a_id = a.id
where a.id in itemsToQuery
```

All the join columns are properly index, and one might think MySQL optimizer would be smart about it.

However, running the explain plan shows that mysql does two full table scans on b_mapping and c_mapping to join on a, and then an index scan on a for the where condition.

I can manually write the following code

```
select * from a
  join (select * from b_mapping where b.a_id in itemsToQuery) b on b.a_id = a.id
  join (select * from c_mapping where c.a_id in itemsToQuery) c on c.a_id = a.id
where a.id in itemsToQuery
```

Which runs basically instantly vs 5 second run on the previous query. The explain plan also shows the that it is now 3 index scans with two joins now.

Is there anyway to force efcore to generate the second SQL code where the condition is brought into the inner loop?

I've read about the new [Include Where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#filtered-include) in efcore5.0 preview 4, which I suspect may do the trick, however pomelo.mysql does not currently support the preview yet.

I have also tried out the [IncludeFilter](https://entityframework-plus.net/ef-core-query-include-filter) in [EntityFrameworkPlus](https://entityframework-plus.net/), however, the performance was even worse.

Comment: for now I think IncludeFilter is the only option, lets wait for EF Core 5

Comment: Did you open bugs for that? On the MySQL Side? Because the SQL looks amazingly fine for me (not using MySQL, but that is how I would just write it to start with) and not recognizing this construct is a brutal omission on the MySQL side - that is "kitchen sql" and the most simple form to express a simple join.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need `IQueryable` result to compose over, you can replace includes with projection and rely on EF Core tracking query navigation property fix-up during the query materialization, e.g.

```
var result = db.A
    .Where(a => itemsToQuery.Contains(a.Id))
    .Select(a => new
    {
        A = a,
        BMappings = a.BMappings.Where(b => itemsToQuery.Contains(b.a_Id)),
        CMappings = a.CMappings.Where(c => itemsToQuery.Contains(c.a_Id)),
    })
    .AsEnumerable() // switch to client eval
    .Select(e => e.A) // extract back the fixed-up entity instance
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible with query syntax, try something like this:

```
var query = from a in db.A.Where(e => itemsToQuery.Contains(e.id))
      join b in db.B.Where(e => itemsToQuery.Contains(e.a_id)) on on b.a_id equals a.id
      join c in db.C.Where(e => itemsToQuery.Contains(e.a_id)) on c on c.a_id equals a.id
      select new {a, b, c};
```

Then you will need to group your results though.

Comment: The problem with this is it is a flattened representation of the query. I would no longer be able to do something like query[0].bMapping.Select(b => b.name).ToList(). I did try this and then grouping it as you said, and to manually populate the bMapping/cMapping back into a, but this too was poorer performance than the original. I'm thinking the grouping performance is lower than the indexed joined within sql

Comment: @EricChen1248 what was performing poorly? Generated query?

Comment: query + C# grouping + C# remapping into 'a' vs the original efcore joined into ICollection.

I did the remapping by doing ```query.Groupby(a => a.id).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList())``` and then a for loop with a.bMapping = dict[a.id]

Comment: @EricChen1248 how many rows do you have for this query returned?

Comment: It loops through different criterias. ranges from 200k to 1m

Comment: @EricChen1248 can you post whole code sample somewhere?

Comment: Something like this. https://gist.github.com/EricChen1248/2fde9f88841b7d019fcc657b2c56b147.
Version 1 was faster than version 2, and not because of the ParallelFor. The CPU is constantly pinned this whole time doing some other calculation. Time measure was for the whole process to finish which includes the data querying.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215809/discussion-between-guru-stron-and-ericchen1248).